# Determining printed map projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography

A friend of mine is working on a small project to map receding North Pole summer sea ice minimums by decadal averages on a wall-paper map.

Unfortunately, it seems as though the map projection for his wall-paper map is non-standard (or closely related to the Robinson projection, but not exactly).

The map in question can be found here:
http://www.pinboardking.com/product/big-red-grey-worldmap/

Due to the fact that the sea ice min/max vectors in the North are very sensitive to projection warping/aberration, I'm trying to find the exact EPSG to be as accurate as possible.

How can the projection be identified or approximated?

Edit: Uploading a picture of said map that I had on hand for better reference.

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing a graticule (lat/lon grid) so I think it's going to be very difficult. It might be cheaper/easier to create a world map in the CRS he wants to use and have it printed.

Comment: This is really hard since they just have pictures and not flat scans.

Comment: Might it be possible to use/ digitize fixed landmarks like towns and markant coastal pattern as ground control points an try to use gdalwarp with a set of coordinate system and higher order transformation for warping and to find the best fitting map.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but it seems the question should be "What might be the best projection to use to show declines in North polar sea ice?" Answer could be "Azimuthal equidistant projection, polar aspect."

Comment: @MartinF you're absolutely right, but the sea ice is mainly side project to add some information to the North of this particular map. The real focus is on climate policy events around the globe.

Comment: When I zoom in on the attached image, the placenames get fuzzy. This could be an interesting project (to map placenames to pixels to latitude/longitude and divine a projection), but it would require some work.